# VB.NET determine which property is not yet assigned a value

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a visual studio 2010 project in VB.NET to import an ASCII file into a databae based on given fields in the ASCII file. Sometimes, there can be some optional fields missing from the ASCII file while importing.

How can I find out which property of a big class has not yet been assigned a value? Based on this, I want to show a form to request for the missing properties at run time!

Comment: If you don't want to keep track of all assigned properties in a list then it depends on the data you need to write. I don't like to use "null" as placeholder but you may consider, if Nothing isn't an allowed value, to use it to detect not assigned properties (using Nullable for value types).

Comment: all fields are string. I don't want 100s of if statements. I just want to read all the ascii file first and then determine which field was not available in the ascii (based on its corresponding property in my class) and finally based on all those missing fields i want to show a form requesting their values before i start writing to the database. so the question remains, how can I quickly determine which field(s) are not assigned a value after i loop throught the whole ascii file?

Comment: Get the value of all properties (via Reflection). Unassigned properties are still null then they're what you have to put if the form.

Comment: @Adriano: please post as an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if there is a faster way,

```
Dim myClassInstance As new MyClass();

If myClassInstance.SomeProperties is Nothing Then 
    'I'm null
End If
```

Do this for all properties that needs to be checked.

Comment: From the OP: `I don't want 100s of if statements...`

Comment: Oooh sorry did not see the comment